# Do we have to santise html passing into Javascript ? How?

Tags: jquery, sanitization

I am passing a `<ul><li></li><ul>`  to jquery .html() method and it works.

I am assigning the html to a varaible and passing to .html() method .

As some security scans suggest me to use `esc_html` on that variable.

But if i use it breaks the menu as it is not rendering html , just printing it as text.

So my question is -Do i have to sanitize HTML when i am passing it to Javascript ,
which is written by me  ?? How ?

Comment: I am using wordpress. If not why should i come here and post it

Comment: Look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: What is the source of the html?

Comment: Hardcoded html menu ..   makes no sense sanitising that . is it?

Comment: nop.. Sanitization is only required when you don't trust the data. For example, user input..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in fact sanitizing the string you listed would remove the HTML. The sanitizing functions are meant for user inputted data like a form submission. You can't always trust the information they pass through. Sometimes hackers may input malicious code that would be executed on your site after submission if you did not run it through a sanitizing function first.